# I have installer java 1.8.0_77, but still get dependencies error

Tags: java

I have a CentOS 7 box. And I have installed Java 1.8.0_77 on it:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

And

```
[root@centos7 ~]# echo $JAVA_HOME
 /opt/install/jdk1.8.0_77
[root@centos7 ~]# echo $JRE_HOME
/opt/install/jdk1.8.0_77/jre
```

But when I try to install a RPM, I still get error:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# rpm -ivh xxxx.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    jre >= 1.8.0_71 is needed by xxxx.x86_64
```

Why?

Comment: It looks like xxxx.x86_64.rpm has a dependency on the OpenJDK JRE, but you have installed the Oracle JRE.  It should not make any difference.  Can you "force" the install of xxxx.x86_64.rpm?

Answer (score 0):

> The package manager is just that - a manager for package information,
>   it doesn't really know whats on your system, just what packages it
>   installed and thus what it assumes is on your system.
>
> The obvious problem with this design is that the two can become out of
>   sync, say, if you installed JRE by hand by downloading it from oracle,
>   then the package manager has no clue that its there and hence does its
>   job of pointing out the failed dependancy chain.
>
> There are multiple options, assuming this is the problem (check your
>   rpm package list, i forget rpm's parameters) in order of uglyness: (1)
>   You can install your distributions version of JRE, which will make the
>   package manager happy, (2) You can fudge the package manager so it
>   thinks said dependancy "jre version 1.7.0" is actually installed, with
>   or without installing it, then subvert the java binaries to use your
>   installed version, or (3) you can just install tomcat with the
>   --nodeps option to ignore dependancies. Be aware (3) is a slippery slope and you'll end up skipping more dependancies and sub
>   dependancies over time.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94091/rpm-failed-jre-dependency-even-though-that-jre-version-is-installed

This worked for me before, hope it solves your issue too.